# Regex sed linux batch

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have this regex:

```
(;)(include_path\s\=\s\")(((?!\").)*)(\")
```

and I want to replace this text:

```
;include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
```

to:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/var/www/html/"
```

the regex replace is:

```
\2\3:/var/www/html/\5
```

I'm using sed in ubuntu 18.04, this is my command:

```
sed -E 's/(;)(include_path \= \")(((?!\").)*)(\")/\2\3:/var/www/html/\5/g' FILENAME
```

But it gives me an error. I used sed style like this:

```
sed -E 's/REGEX/REPLACE/g' FILENAME
```

Comment: `I have this regex` is a bad way to start trying to solve any problem :-). [edit] your question to show the text you want to replace **in context** with other text and the expected output. matching the text you want to find is always the easy part, it's not matching the other text you do not want to find that's hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a lookahead in a `sed` pattern. However, your tempered greedy token `(?:(?!\").)*` can be simply converted to a negated bracket expression that `sed` supports, `[^"]*`.

Besides, you need other regex delimiters since `/` are used in the replacement pattern, e.g. `|`.

Use

```
sed -E 's|;(include_path = ")([^"]*)(")|\1\2:/var/www/html/\3|g' FILENAME
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/nPWusZ):

```
s=';include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"'
echo $s | sed -E 's|;(include_path = ")([^"]*)(")|\1\2:/var/www/html/\3|g'
# => include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/var/www/html/"
```

**Details**

- `;` - a semi-colon (no need to capture it if you need to discard it)
- `(include_path = ")` - a literal text captured into Group 1 (`\1`)
- `([^"]*)` - any 0+ chars other than `"`  captured into Group 2 (`\2`)
- `(")` - a `"` captured into Group 3 (`\3`).

Comment: Perfect! This works! In other examples the separator of commands is \ instead |

Comment: The escape character `\ ` would be a terrible choice of separator.

Comment: @EdMorton: I think it's a typo, he means `/`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte What are you talking about? I have not mentioned any ``\`` separators.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte :) Ok, I did not quite get that comment, it is 1:00 AM here...

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes, i mean / in other examples I saw this character instead |

Answer (score 2):

From what you've told us so far it sounds like this is all you need:

```
$ sed 's#;\(include_path = "[^"]*\)#\1:/var/www/html/#' file
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/var/www/html/"
```

The above will work using any sed in any shell on any UNIX box.